# How can I detect endianness on a system

Tags: java, algorithm, endianness

How can I detect endianness on a system in java?I dont want to use inbuilt methods
as its a interview question. Also how to convert big to small and vice versa?

Am looking for ans using Java and not C/C++. I had found such links
[Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program)

Comment: If an interviewer wants you to program in Java without using any inbuilt methods then you probably want to call them on that. :)

Comment: If for a minute I put aside that it's just a silly interview question, why would anyone want to know the endianness in Java? It isn't ever going to matter, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't `java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder()` give it to you?

Check the source of that.

Comment: OP said: "I dont want to use inbuilt methods as its a interview question"

Comment: That method eventually does something dirty with Unsafe. Which is build-in. If there's any way around using that, it's magic.