# Pointer to lowest address in memory

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program)

I'm trying to check if I'm running a little or big endian OS.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1; 
    unsigned char b = i; 
    char *c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i); // line 5

    cout << "Processor identified as: " << endl;

    if (*c == b) 
        cout << "Little endian" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Big endian" << endl;
}
```

I'm not sure if casting an `int*` to `char*` pointer in line 5 is guaranteed to return a lowest address. Am I doing it right?

Comment: You are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program  no need for pointers here

Comment: My question is about `int to char*` not "How to check endianness?"

Comment: Looks awfully like the latter to me.

Answer (score 0):

It might give you the bottom address of the call stack (of the main thread).

But heap addresses may compare lower (or upper) to that address.

Also, stack growth direction is orthogonoal to endianess.

Comment: This does not make sense as an answer, reread the question, it is actually asking whether the reinterpret is guaranteed to return the lowest address of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard does not place any restrictions on the byte content of an integer. You may find some systems that are neither little nor big endian - eg, the PDP-11 used a format in which `0x0A0B0C0D` was stored as `0B 0A 0D 0C`. It's also allowed for there not to be any `0x01` byte at all in the representation for `1`.

As for whether the cast will return the lowest byte in the int, it will. However, again, the content of this byte is not well-defined by the C++ specification.

Comment: Unrelated, the question is whether the reinterpret cast will retrieve the first byte of the integer, not about endianness ingeneral

Answer (score 0):

Your char will have the same address as your int, which will be the lowest address of any byte in the int. In don't know if this is actually guaranteed, but it's true on every system I've ever used.