# How can I find Endian-ness of my PC programmatically using C?

Tags: c, endianness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program)

Is there any library function available to find the endian-ness of my PC?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Why you need a library if you can find it like this? :)

```
int num = 1;

if (*(char *)&num == 1)
{
    printf("Little-Endian\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Big-Endian\n");
}
```

Comment: maybe explain why this works like @Eric J. does below

Comment: int num=1 will stored as 000.0001 or 100.000 depending on endianness. (char*)&num will be pointing to first byte of that int. now if that byte reads 1, then its little endian otherwise big endian.

Comment: @hasanatkazmi How do you know if the computer will store the number in 2 bytes or 4 bytes? Also, why are you using 7 bits anyway?

Comment: @hasanatkazmi: Looks like you mix endianess with bit ordering within a byte (for example motorola docs show bit order the opposite way contrary to the rest of the world)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a library function.

You can get the address of an integer, then treat that address as a character pointer and write data into the bytes that comprise the integer.  Then, read out what is actually in the integer and see if you get a result consistent with a big endian or little endian architecture.

Answer (score 6):

use this code:

```
union 
{
    uint8  c[4];
    uint32 i;
} u;

u.i = 0x01020304;

if (0x04 == u.c[0])
    printf("Little endian\n");
else if (0x01 == u.c[0])
    printf("Big endian\n");
```

Comment: You do not need "else if" - "else" is enough since if it is not little endianess it is big endianess.

Comment: @Artur: ha ha ha ha!  There are other alternatives: PDP11 used 16-bit words in big-endian order ... with the bytes in the word in little-endian order (it might have been visa-versa - it was a while ago now).

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a standard function to do so (as in C standard, or POSIX standard).

If your PC is a (Windows-style) PC running Intel, it is little-endian.

If you wish to find the byte-order on your machine, you can use the not wholly defined behaviour (but it usually works - I've not heard of anywhere that it doesn't work) of this technique:

```
enum { BigEndian, LittleEndian };

int endianness(void)
{
    union
    {
        int  i;
        char b[sizeof(int)];
    } u;
    u.i = 0x01020304;
    return (u.b[0] == 0x01) ? BigEndian : LittleEndian;
}
```

This code does assume a 32-bit `int` type (rather than 64-bit or 16-bit).

Comment: Why not `u.i = 1; return u.b[0] == 1 ? LittleEndian : BigEndian;` ?  That way you don't have to worry about the int size.

Comment: @MartinBonner: that would also work.

Comment: AMD little endian too?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd — AMD chips are “Intel-compatible” and therefore little-endian.  SPARC and PowerPC are the main big-endian chips these days.  Modern PPC chips can be switched to little-endian — there are PPCLE versions of Linux.