# How to force stream to write numeric data according to type

Tags: c++, stream

I use `wofstream` to merge files and also write wstrings and integers (right from the memory). My problem (for now) is let's say I have `int32` which holds number `7`. In memory it takes 4 bytes, but when I write it to stream, and check it with hex viewer I see just this -- `7` (single byte).

Of course this is no use for me, because I have to read it and read it reliably.

So how to make stream to write data according to type -- so 2 bytes type will take 2 bytes, 4 bytes -- 4 bytes, and so on?

For the record my merge function:

```
for (const std::wstring &fn : files)  
{
    std::wifstream is_src(dst_dir+fn, std::ios_base::binary);

    os_dest << is_src.rdbuf();
    os_dest << fn;
    os_dest << static_cast<__int32>(fn.size());
}

os_dest << static_cast<__int32>(files.size());
```

I added casting to be 100% sure there are 4 bytes and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [writing integer to binary file (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244563/writing-integer-to-binary-file-c)

The key is not to use stream operator, but method `write`.