# Seeing value being stored in memory to check endianess?

Tags: c

If I debug this C code:

```
unsigned int i = 0xFF;
```

Will the debugger show me in memory 0x00FF if it's a little endian system and 0xFF00 if it's a big endian system?

Comment: That kind of depends on the way your debugger displays memory.

Comment: None of the debuggers I know do that. You can have the debugger show a range of memory though, as separate bytes.

Comment: @user1091856 Sorry, which logic? To print an int as 0xFF00 if its value is 0x00FF? Also, what compiler? Most compilers have 32 bits ints.

Comment: Depends on how you choose display memory, i.e. as bytes, words, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you view the raw contents of memory around the address `&i` then yes, you will be able to tell the difference. But it's going to be `00 00 00 ff` for big endian and `ff 00 00 00` for little endian, assuming `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 4 and `CHAR_BIT` (number of bits per byte) is 8 -- in the question you have them swapped.

You can also detect endianness programmatically (i.e. you can make a program that prints out the endianness of the architecture it runs on) through one of several tricks; for example, see [Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program) (solutions apply to C too).

Comment: no, the C standard doesn't specify the size of an int, so it can vary between different systems.

Comment: @user1091856: No, it's *at least* 2 bytes.

Comment: @Jon: no, `int` is at least `16 bits`, not `2 bytes`. A byte in C can be bigger than 8 bits. A typical example of such an implementation would be C for TI's DSPs such as TMS320C54xx (in there `char`=`short`=`int`=16 bits=single addressable unit of memory).

Comment: @Alex: Agreed, but I don't think the difference is something the OP needs to be force-fed in this context because it dilutes the essence of the answer to this question.

Comment: @Jon: I think when programming in C one has to make a clear distinction between a `C byte` and an `8-bit byte` to avoid undue confusion and bugs. For this very reason in a number of places the word `byte` is either defined or replaced by the word `octet`.

Comment: @Alex: Again, I agree. But you don't teach someone pointer arithmetic the same day you teach them "Hello world". There are innumerable amateur (and even "professional") C programmers who have no idea about `CHAR_BIT` or even the size limits of `int`, and yet they do manage to write programs.

Comment: @Jon: We haven't got there yet. :)

Answer (score 2):

If:

- Your system has 8-bit `char`s.
- Your system uses 16-bit `unsigned int`s
- And your debugger displays memory as simply bytes of hex

You would see this at `&i` if it's little-endian:

```
ff 00 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??
```

and this if it's big-endian:

```
00 ff ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??
```

The question marks simply represent the bytes following `i` in memory.

Note that:

- A little-endian machine will store the byte with the lowest value at the lowest address.
- A big-endian machine will store the byte with the largest value at the lowest address.
- C doesn't specify how many bits are in an `unsigned int`. It's up to the implementation.
- You can find out using `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned int)`.

If instead your machine uses 32-bit `unsigned char`, you would see:

```
ff 00 00 00 ?? ?? ?? ??
```

in the little-endian case, and on a big-endian machine you would see:

```
00 00 00 ff ?? ?? ?? ??
```