# java to C/C++(carbide c/c++) converstion

Tags: java, c++, c, symbian

In Java :

value = 1122;

```
public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
        return new byte[] {
                (byte)(value >>> 24),
                (byte)(value >>> 16),
                (byte)(value >>> 8),
                (byte)value};
    }

  public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] data) {
        return (int)(
                (int)(0xff & data[0]) << 24  |
                (int)(0xff & data[1]) << 16  |
                (int)(0xff & data[2]) << 8   |
                (int)(0xff & data[3]) << 0
        );
    }
```

here it'll return [0, 0, 4, 98] so in 
C:

```
char* intToByteArray(int value){
        char* temp = new char[4];
         temp[0] = value >> 24,
         temp[1] = value >> 16,
         temp[2] = value >> 8, 
         temp[3] = value;
         return temp;
}
```

since there's no byte data type in c we can use char* instead of that but when i return temp value i am getting null so i checked values like this where =  b\x04 'b'= 98, x04 = 4 i am not able to get data which is zero so while converting back how should i manage remaining values??

```
         char* where = new char[10];
         where[0] = temp[3];
         where[1] = temp[2];
         where[2] = temp[1];
         where[3] = temp[0];
         where[4] = 0;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but this code works fine for me. The values of temp and where were both set properly. Are you sure you're using the "==" operator. I don't see why you can't do " where[3] == 0". There's no reason you shouldn't be able to get data that's 0.

Answer (score 3):

> i am getting null

No you are not. You are getting a first byte which is a `\0` nul byte. When you print this as a text string it will terminate the string. But its not a string, its an array of bytes.

If you were getting a NULL, you would get a segmentation fault or the like.

Comment: ya sorry getting \x00 value but what about remaining values how to get those and store in array.here only i am facing difficulty.

Comment: You can get those with `bytes[0]`, `bytes[1]` `bytes[2]` and `bytes[3]` like an array. ;)

Comment: ya like this i can get all values int tt = temp[0];int tt1 = temp[1];int tt2 = temp[2];int tt3 = temp[3]; but i cant store all those values in array as bytes:(. is it possible to store like this  \x00\x00\x04\x98??

Comment: A `char*`  is a pointer to an array of bytes. Doesn't `temp` have all those values in an array as bytes.

Answer (score 0):

While the above post is absolutely correct, you have one more serious problem with your porting effort. Your java produces

```
[ 0, 0, 4, 98 ]
```

while your C produces

```
[ 98, 4, 0, 0 ]
```

The code won't work when simply converted like that. Java is big-endian regardless of the hardware, but your C(++) unsurprisingly is low-endian. Worse still, you cannot be sure that it will be that way every time. With Carbide, i guess that you can perfectly stumble upon a big endian architecture (some ARMs? not an expert in this field). So you must either [detect endian-ness of your Carbide platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program) or, replace the bitshift with an incremental modulo 256. Depends on how often you call the function. Modulo will take seriously more processor effort but doesn't care about endianness.

Comment: sorry,actually c also produces like java only but starting zero is there so rest of the values i am not able to see i made it reverse using other variable as mentioned in above code.