# How to know that our system follows little endian or big endian using C++?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

How to know that our system follows little endian or big endian ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program

Comment: Do you want to check it programatically, or do you just want to know if your platforms endianess? If the first, there are many ways of doing it if you just search a little, if the latter then it depends on your processor and not your operating system.

Answer (score 2):

```
int n = 1;
// little endian if true else big endian
if(*(char *)&n == 1) {...}
```