# convert from big to little endian c++

Tags: c++, endianness

I'm working on a homework assignment to print out big and little endian values of an `int` and `float`. I'm having trouble converting to little endian.

here's my code

```
void convertLitteE(string input)
{
    int theInt;
    stringstream stream(input);
    while(stream >> theInt)
    {
        float f = (float)theInt;

        printf("\n%d\n",theInt);
        printf("int:   0x");
        printLittle((char *) &theInt, sizeof(theInt));

        printf("\nfloat: 0x");
        printLittle((char *) &f, sizeof(f));
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

void printLittle(char *p, int nBytes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nBytes; i++, p++)
    {
        printf("%02X", *p);
    }
}
```

when input is 12 I get what I would expect

```
output:
int:   0x0C000000
float: 0x00004041
```

but when input is 1234

```
output:
int:   0xFFFFFFD20400000
float: 0x0040FFFFFFF9A44
```

but I would expect

```
int :  0xD2040000
float: 0x00409A44
```

When I step through the `for` loop I can see where there appears to be a garbage value and then it prints all the `F`'s but I don't know why. I've tried this so many different ways but I can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm using a string because we have to be able to enter in multiple numbers at once. So i just use getline then get the number values from the string.

Comment: What language is this?  C++?  You need to tag your question with the language in use.

Comment: @Jeff It looks like `convertLitteE` is supposed to convert from a decimal string to little-endian hexadecimal output.  No fundamental issue with that part.

Comment: Your approach seems to be to print the bytes of the internal representation of the `int`, one by one. That is not guaranteed to give you a little-endian integer representation. It will give you whatever representation your system uses for integers.

Comment: @jogojapan true, but for this homework assignment I'm assuming the system is big endian.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program)

Comment: Looks like dup for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently on your system, `char` is a signed 8-bit type.  Using unsigned 8-bit bytes, the 4-byte little-endian representation of 1234 would be `0xd2, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00`.  But when interpreted as a signed `char` on most systems, `0xd2` becomes `-0x2e`.

Then the call to `printf` promotes that `char` to the `int` with value `-0x2e`, then `printf` (which is not very typesafe) reads in an `unsigned int` where you passed the `int`.  This is Undefined Behavior, but on most systems it will be the same as a `static_cast`, so you get the value `0xFFFFFFD2` when trying to print the first byte.

If you stick to using `unsigned char` instead of `char` in these functions, you can avoid this particular problem.

(But as @jogojapan pointed out, this entire approach is not portable at all.)