# pointers to point proper memory location

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a bit of C code in which I am presented with following things:

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
typedef int8_t SBYTE;
typedef uint16_t WORD;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef uint64_t QWORD;
```

I have a function having definition as `QWORD exp_d(const DWORD *in)`.

And I have a pointer to a QWORD as `QWORD* input`. Being a QWORD, it is of 64 bits. Now, I want to send the least-significant 32 bits of `input` to function `exp_d`. What I am doing is,

`QWORD expansion=exp_d(((DWORD*)input)+1);`

I think, `input` is a `QWORD*`, so first typecasting it to a `DWORD*`, and then incrimenting it by 1 (to get to next `DWORD`, i.e. least significant 32 bits of `QWORD`) should do the thing. However, when I pass such value to `exp_d`, I get the most significant 32 bits of `input` rather than least significant 32 bits as expected.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If function `exp_d` can't be modified, then you might need to define another function which return the pointer to lower 32 bits from 64 bits pointer. Inside function, return address according to your system endianness.

```
DWORD * GetDwordFromQword(const QWORD *input)
{
    if(BigEndian()) {
        return (DWORD*)input+1;
    } else {
        return (DWORD*)input;
    }
}
```

`BigEndian()` definition can refer here [Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 1):

Use the numeric value, if the type of the input is `QWORD`:

```
(uint32_t) ((*input) & 0xffffffff)
```