# Convert short array to byte array and vice-versa and int to byte array and vice-versa in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, int, byte, arrays, short

I am confused to convert byte array to short vice-versa and also int to byte array vice-versa in Objective-C.

I have seen in Java like following

```
  public static short byteArrayToShort(byte[] b) {
    if (b.length > 1) {
        return (ByteBuffer.wrap(b)).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get();
    } else {
        return b[0];
    }
}

/**
 * Short to byte array.
 *
 * @param value the value
 * @return the byte[]
 */
public static byte[] shortToByteArray(short value) {
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putShort(value).array();
}

/**
 * Int to byte array.
 *
 * @param value the value
 * @return the byte[]
 */
public static byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(value).array();
}

/**
 * Convert the byte array to an short starting from the given offset.
 * 
 * @param b The byte array
 * @return The integer
 */
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
    if (b.length > 1) {
        return (ByteBuffer.wrap(b)).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer().get();
    } else {
        return b[0];
    }
}
```

In Objective-C I have tried like following:

```
//Byte to Short array
- (uint16_t*) byte2short:(uint8_t *)bytes size:(int)size{
    uint16_t*shorts = (uint16_t*)malloc(size/2);
    for (int i=0; i < size/2; i++){
       shorts[i] = (bytes[i*2+1] << 8) | bytes[i*2];
    }
    return shorts;
}
//Short to Byte array
- (uint8_t *) short2byte:(uint16_t*)shorts size:(int)size{

    uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)malloc(size*2);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        bytes[i * 2] = (uint16_t) (shorts[i] & 0x00FF);
        bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (uint16_t) (shorts[i] >> 8);
        shorts[i] = 0;
    }
    return bytes;
  }
```

I have tried like this and also I dont have idea in conversion of int to Byte array in Objective-c.

Please suggest me

Comment: This isn't a free code conversion site. Please make your own attempt first. Post what you have tried and explain what issue you are having.

Comment: Please check the question now. I am really sorry for earlier question.

Comment: You should put back the original Java code so people can compare against your Objective-C code.

Comment: I did that. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are assuming that `malloc` somehow "knows" about the size of whatever is being allocated, in the same way that Java's array `new` knows the difference between allocating 5 `int`s and 5 `short`s. Well, `malloc` does not. Unless you tell it otherwise, it allocates the required number of bytes. That's why when you do this

```
uint16_t*shorts = (uint16_t*)malloc(size/2);
```

and then write `size/2` `uint16_t` into it, you overrun the buffer.

A proper way of allocating an array of primitives in C (and in Objective-C, which is a superset of C) is as follows:

```
size_t count = (size+1)/2; // Do not assume that size is even
uint16_t *shorts = malloc(sizeof(uint16_t)*count);
```

Now you have enough memory to fit all your shorts.

In your other function you should use

```
uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*size*2);
```

Note that the cast is unnecessary in both cases. The type of `bytes` variable matters, though, because that's what determines the actual address written to in `bytes[i * 2]` and `bytes[(i * 2)+1]` expressions:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    bytes[i * 2] = (uint8_t) (shorts[i] & 0xFF);
    bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (uint8_t) (shorts[i] >> 8);
    shorts[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. How can I convert int to Byte array and vice-versa.

Comment: @iOS_DeviOS You can take the same approach as in your `unit16_t` code, but now that you have `uint32_t`, you need to process four bytes at a time instead of two bytes at a time.

Comment: @iOS_DeviOS No, that would be `bytes[i * 4] = (uint8_t) (ints[i] & 0xFF);` and `bytes[(i * 4)+1] = (uint8_t) ((ints[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);`, but you would also add `bytes[(i * 4)+2] = (uint8_t) ((ints[i] >> 16) & 0xFF);` and `bytes[(i * 4)+3] = (uint8_t) ((ints[i] >> 24) & 0xFF);`. I hope you see the pattern there - going for the next byte makes you shift an additional 8 bits to the right before masking the result with `0xFF`.

Comment: Excellent dasblinknlight. Thanks alot for your answer.  And also in java, they are checking `LITTLE_ENDIAN`. How can I check in iOS? And also all ios devices are LITTLE_ENDIAN?

Comment: @iOS_DeviOS I think that all iOS devices are little endian at the moment. However, this may change if Apple decides to go with a different processor architecture at some time in the future. It's best to use a little trick for checking endianness described [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1001373/335858).

Comment: thanks alot for your help. I will try with all your suggestions and will gt back to you. Thanks alot once again.