# I can not overflow buffer

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

I have seen a buffer overflow code but I can not over flow it. Is there any gcc option to compile that? Or any wrong with that code.

The code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     volatile int modified;
     char buffer[64];

     if(argc == 1) {
          errx(1, "please specify an argument\n");
     }

     modified = 0;
     strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

     if(modified == 0x61626364) {
            printf("you have correctly got the variable to the right value\n");
     } else {
            printf("Try again, you got 0x%08x\n", modified);
     }
}
```

and I am trying to run it this way:
`perl -e 'print "A"x64 . "dcba"' | xargs ./main`

Comment: This is notoriously tricky to get right without looking at the generated code. What are you getting? Does the process crash?

Comment: Overflowing `buffer` will write to the memory following it, but `modified` is probably in the memory preceding it (depending on the compiler).

Comment: This is a ctf challenge [here](http://exploit-exercises.com/protostar/stack1) is the question

Comment: @ interjay: Do you know any compiler can compile this ? or gcc option ?

Comment: Maybe try to overflow it while putting it inside a struct. As far as I understand all compilers will keep the struct order since you might count on it when coding.

Comment: So what output did you get? It works fine on cygwin gcc.

Comment: my result is `Try again, you got 0x00000000` but it must be `you have correctly got the variable to the right value\n`. I'm using debian

Comment: @M.Fooladgar How are you compiling? Have you tried feeding it a longer string? Perhaps your stack is padded.

Comment: @molbdnilo: yes and the result is: `*** stack smashing detected ***: ./level5 terminated`. and the compiling is easy `gcc main.c -o main`. The gcc version is `4.8.2`

Comment: @M.Fooladgar You need to disable the "smash detection".  `-f-no-stack-protector`, I think. The zeros are stored between the variables so overruns can be detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know

1. Know the stack memory layout and the address difference between the variable `modified` and `buffer`
   You can solve it by finding the offset between modified and buffer as `(char *)&modified - (char *)buffer`
2. Your machine endianess. I have used the [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001373/977038) answer for this purpose

The linked demonstrates how to run the modified code that serves the purpose of determining the correct argument as well as stack smashing. The first [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d760b2c3d00b9240) provides you with the argument that you can feed to your second [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b5846c7184be825)