# Trying to write endianess detection program, but can't compare char values

Tags: c, endianness

I'm trying to write a program that detects endianess and returns the  endianess type (1 for little, 0 for big) or -1 if none of them.
but I encountered this problem: when I try to mask unsigned long word with an unsigned char, and then I try to compare this char to is ASCII value the code inside the if condition becomes unreachable appearrantly...

```
int is_little_endian() {
    unsigned long word = 0x6600000000000088;
    unsigned char maskedWord = word;
    if (maskedWord == 'X') {
        return 0;
    } else if (maskedWord == 'B') {
        return 1;
    } else return -1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't post pictures of code!

Comment: removed my code picture

Comment: i.e. **post the actual code**, not pictures of the code

Comment: Use the implementation-specific macros. Or use compliant code. This one is broken in many aspects: 1) assumes ASCII encoding 2) possibly too large integer constant for `unsigned long`, 3) The 2nd initialiser should generate a conversion warning (always enable all recommended warnings and treat them as errors!), unless `char` has more than 62 bits on your platform. It also does not work for obvious reasons. FInally: Th name implies a boolean result, but you return three results. That's a bad naming scheme or approach.

Comment: What is your question?  I guess you might refer to some compiler warning message ; if so then post the message (and make sure your code is a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: You should try to stick to a 32-bit value when doing this for portability reasons. Also be aware of the fact that some CPUs have the capability of switching data endianness at runtime (i.e. toggling a CPU flag can switch data from big to little and vice-versa), and some can even store a value in a "middle-endian" byte order when an unaligned 32-bit write is performed in a particular way: [example of middle-endian issue (Twitter)](https://twitter.com/isislovecruft/status/455924593711411200) and [Wikipedia info on middle-endian data format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian)

Comment: A very clever answer is given at the following link, which uses `int isBigEndian = (htonl(X) == X);`
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program/1001330#1001330

Answer (score 2):

You can check endianness without using a `union`, with any type taking at least two bytes

```
uint32_t val = 1;
int big_endian = !(*(char *)&val);
```

In memory (for a 4-bytes `int`), big endian would be

```
     val:  00 00 00 01
- ============(addresses)======> +
```

Little endian:

```
     val:  01 00 00 00
- ============(addresses)======> +
```

Comment: Some ARM machines can still be a form of "middle-endian" (i.e. `0B 0A 0D 0C` or `0C 0D 0A 0B` to represent `0x0A0B0C0D`) when dealing with unaligned data. This usually won't be a problem, but it's not like there's a guarantee it won't happen. A reply to [this annoyed Twitter post](https://twitter.com/isislovecruft/status/455924593711411200) illustrates how such a thing might happen; the idea is that you perform an unaligned 32-bit write to a 16-bit-aligned address (i.e. `addr % 4 == 2`). Shouldn't happen ordinarily, but it's clearly possible. Some CPUs can switch endianness at runtime too :(

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b this is legal by the standards and no compiler should reject it.

Comment: I stand corrected.  It does indeed compile with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror`.  I deleted the comment. (and upvoted this solution)

Answer (score 1):

This code won't successfully test for endianness.

You define `unsigned long word = 0x6600000000000088`.  Ignoring for a moment that this constant might be too large for an `unsigned long`, when you assign that value to an `unsigned char` it gets truncated modulo 256, so `maskedWord` will always equal 0x88.

To do a proper endianness test, you need to create a union of a char array and a fixed size integer and assign bytes to the char array, then check the value of the integer.

```
union echeck {
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    uint32_t val;
};
echeck e = { .bytes = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 } };
if (e.val == 0x01020304) {
    printf("big endian\n");
} else if (e.val == 0x04030201) {
    printf("little endian\n");
} else {
    printf("neither big or little endian\n");
}
```

Comment: The behavior of C is technically undefined when accessing a union member that was not the last member assigned.  That said, every compiler I've seen will compile this the way you expect.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b AFAIK it was defined post C99. But I would rather use dereferencing by casting a pointer to `char*` here.

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite wrong. The result of converting `0x6600000000000088` to `unsigned char` will result in `0x88` on octet-addressable platforms, be they little or big or middle-endian.

Then another problem is that `'B'` is 66 on an ASCII machine, yes, and `'Z'` is 88 - but in decimal. But the `66` and `88` are in *hex* in your program. `0x66` corresponds to `'f'` and `88` is some extended character.

Instead of all this mess, use simply

```
union {
    uint64_t test_value;
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof(uint64_t)];
} detect = { .test_value = 0x0102030405060708 };
```

and check the values of `detector.bytes[0]` to `detector.bytes[7]`

Comment: we are not allowed to use outside libraries, and the word has to be long...

Comment: @Blur: `stdint.h` is not an "outside library", but a standard libary which is mandatory for every implementation. If your assignment disallows that,  you are learning bad coding style.

Comment: There is no need to use the (likely) largest standard type. `uint16_t` would be sufficient. Also use `uint8_t` instead of `unsigned char`. There is no guarantee `unsigned char` has 8 bits and that way a compile error will show if the platform does not support 8 bit types. While this might sound nitpicky, it does not add any extra effort/code and a beginner schould always learn to write good code - the exceptions from this rule will come later once he knows when to bend the rules **and why**..

Comment: In general, using a compiler-macro would be the better approach, **iff** such testing is requred at all. Typically one writes the code such that it runs on both endianesses(?!) correctly. (on a sidenote: `sizeof` here requires the parentheses.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a candidate that I think honors the C type-punning rules, presuming that memcpy is okay.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  uint32_t test;
  uint8_t trial[4] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67};

  memcpy(&test, trial, 4);
  switch(test)
  {
    case 0x01234567: printf("Big Endian\n"); break;
    case 0x67452301: printf("Little Endian\n"); break;
    case 0x45670123:
    case 0x23016745: printf("Middle Endian\n"); break;
    default: printf("WTF?\n"); break;
  };
}
```

I suppose if you have to use long, you could split it into cases for sizeof(long) = 4 and sizeof(long) = 8...