# Is there a template-meta program to determine the endianness of the compiler at compile time?

Tags: c++, c, boost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to do a C++ style compile-time assertion to determine machine's endianness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280162/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-c-style-compile-time-assertion-to-determine-machines-en)

I am looking for a template meta program in the spirit of Boost::type_traits that would return whether the compiler is big or little endian. Something like `is_big_endian<T>`. How do I write this?

The use of this is to create a library that will automatically adapt itself to the environment, by implementing specific template specialization based on the endian-ness. For example,

```
template<>
void copy_big_endian_impl<true>(T *dst, const T *src, size_t sz) {
         // since already big endian, we just copy
         memcpy(dst, src, sz*sizeof(T));
}
template<>
void copy_big_endian_impl<false>(T *dst, const T *src, size_t sz) {
         for (int idx=0; idx<sz; idx++)
             dst[idx] = flip(src[idx];
}
```

This would allow is_big_endian to be passed as a template argument.

Comment: What you probably need is not metaprogramming but old fashioned macros. Architecture-specific headers often contain that sort of information, maybe there's a boost header that will have a cross-platform way of getting it though.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Boost header file that defines a macro you can use: [boost/detail/endian.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/detail/endian.hpp). There's no need to resort to template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 3):

if you're using gcc (or clang), you can use the preprocessor variable **__BYTE_ORDER__**:

```
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
// little endian stuff
#else
// big endian stuff
#endif // __BYTE_ORDER__
```